# Design a greedy algorithm by intermingling two sequences

Tags: algorithms, greedy-algorithms

I find myself solving problems for a test and the next problem I still can't solve it.
There are n ordered sequences, $S_1$ to $S_n$. It is requested to  intermingling them to obtain a single sequence, but doing the minimum possible work. The sequences are interspersed by two, the interleaving sequences $A$ and $B$ a long sequence is obtained $| A | + | B |$ , and the work done is proportional to the length of the resulting sequence.

1 - Create an algorithm to perform this task, choosing pairs of sequences to be inserted in each step.

2 - What is the total cost of your algorithm, in terms of the lengths of the original sequences?

3 - Show that your algorithm delivers an optimal sequence.

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is just Huffman’s algorithm. I answered an equivalent question recently.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you happen to have the link to that answer?

Comment: Unfortunately the search facilities around here are quite bad.